# How to initialize "ostream &out" in constructor, using "char *filename"

Tags: c++

Please help me in initializing "out" in the constructor?

```
class logger {
        ostream &out;

        public:
        logger(char *str) : out(/*How do i construct an object using str*/) {}    

        template <typename T> void print(T &obj) { out << obj; }
};
```

This class will be defined globally for others to just call the print method

UPDATE:
    I am planning to have below setup, where user of class can
1) create a new ostream object if he does not have one. He can create but he have to manage it as well. So do not want to give the feature.
2) If he have already have one he can pass on like "cout/cerr".
3) If he passes nothing "cerr" will be assumed.

{

```
    ostream &out;

    public:
    logger() : out(cerr) {}         
    logger(ostream &o) : out(o){}
    logger(char *str) : out(/*How do i construct an object using str*/) {}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to create an output stream that is connected to the provided filename? E.g. logger l = new logger("foo.txt"); would create an ostream and open "foo.txt" for writing?

Comment: Yes... "l" will be available globally...

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for you to declare the stream as a reference, unless you want to be able to initialize from another stream. Something like this maybe:

```
class logger
{
    ofstream file;
    ostream &out;

public:
    logger(char *str) : file(str), out(file) {}
    logger(ostream &os) : out(os) {}

    // Other functions here, only using "out"
};
```

Comment: "There is no need for you to declare the stream as a reference, unless you want to set it from another stream later." that does not make much sense, as references can not be changed.

Comment: Just a nit, but I'd inverse the order of the declarations.  Regardless of what you write in the constructor, `out` will be constructed _before_ `file`.  And until `file` is constructed, converting it to an `ostream&` is formally undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes.  (The general strategy is good, and I've used it once or twice.)

Answer (score 2):

About the only solution which would work would be:

```
logger::logger( char const* name ) : out( *new std::ofstream( name ) ) {}
```

But you don't want to do this; you'd also have to delete it in the
destructor.  If you have a reference to an `std::ostream` in the class,
you want client code to pass you a reference to an existing `ostream` 
object in the constructor—an object which they guarantee will
continue to exist as long as your object exists.  If you want to pass in
a filename, and open it in the constructor, then your object should
contain an `std::ofstream`, and not a reference.